# XeTeX crashing when including PDF files with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, xetex

I've only used XeTeX a little so far for Greek text and it's the first time I am trying to include figures. `\includegraphics` works fine with `PNG` images but when I try `PDF` files, it just crashes. Here's a minimal sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text.

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The same sample works with `fig.png` instead of `fig.pdf`. It also works perfectly for both file types with PDFTeX. I am using the following XeTeX version:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

on Ubuntu 12.04 (with package `texlive-full` installed). Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should update. On MiKTeX 2.9, I have version 0.99993.

Comment: Just want to make sure (this *might* be a reason): this is *not* a file called `fig.tex`, right? ;)

Comment: @mbork No, it is not :-)

Comment: Your XeTeX version is completely outdated! I recommend TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Could there be anything wrong with the source PDF? Can pdfTeX include it? I also recommend updating, but if the problem persists…

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't think so, I've tried several. It must be the outdated version. Too bad this one came with Ubuntu, now I need to manually update somehow.

Comment: Hi again, I've installed TeX Live 2012 following [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012), but crashing persists. Any other idea? By the way, there was some crash report I saw once where the stack trace indicated some font look-up function of `libpoppler` was the last called before the crash. But I didn't keep any details and this report doesn't always come up. I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: @iavr is this one solved?

Comment: @Paul I don't remember, I think not. Certainly the update did not help. I think it was a problem with the specific PDF files I was trying; it was working with some other PDF files. So I had to re-make these files or something. I did my job but was quite frustrating.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only reproducible with specific PDF files that haven't been provided.

Comment: @Paul Indeed, I just didn't know that when I asked, and now I don't even remember what the files were. Sorry.

Comment: @iavr no need to be sorry, and _I_ apologize if my comment came across badly. It's simply an automated comment that lists my reason for voting to close. Nothing you did wrong, but we try to keep questions on this site applicable to a broad audience, which is why I voted to close this one.